# What's the Latin for motorcycle

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

A long time ago, probably when I was auditing botanical Latin, I recall someone saying what the Latin word for motorcycle would be. It was a long and literal description of what one is given that such machines didn't exist when Latin was "alive." Online searches aren't helping. Anyone familiar with this and care to share? Gratias tibi.

Answer (score 10):

*Harrius Potter et Philosophi Lapis* has *birotula automataria.* Quite similar to Canned Man's answer.

Comment: This--well, actually *birota automata*, without the diminutive--is also what the [Neo-Latin Lexicon](https://neolatinlexicon.org/latin/) suggests, citing EGGER S.L. 29; and Bacci IOE 21.

Comment: @brianpck And the Romans likely would have defaulted to just *birota* (or I suppose *birotula*, but maybe that for scooters). Can you imagine the Romans saying *currus quadrigarum* every time they referred to the *quadrigae*?

Comment: Maybe _birotula_ then could be a good word for a (motorised) scooter or a moped?

Answer (score 8):

I will make a suggestion. *Prīmum, ecce Pondus, composuit et pīnxit Frode Øverli:*

[image: Fābula dē Pondō quī birotam cōnstruit.]

*Fābula dē Pondō quī birotam cōnstruit. – The story about Pondus who builds a bicycle.

Composuit et pīnxit: Frode Øverli. In latīnum convertit: Tor Ivar Østmoe. © Øverli 2007. MareSilva.*

The word *bicycle* and *bĭrŏta* are almost literally the same. The prefix *bi-* stems from the Latin counting adverb *bis*, and note that:

> The word bis (“twice”) drops the s when making compositions, like the Greek word δίς (dís, “dis”).

English *cycle* stems from Greek κύκλος: circle, ring. The Latin *rota, -ae* means wheel. Now we can get some inspiration from Whitaker’s Words for how to make it automatic:

> autocinetum, autocineti  N  N     2 2  N   [GTXDK]
> car;
>
> autocineticus, autocinetica, autocineticum  ADJ    [GXXDK]
> car-; of a car;
>
> autoraeda, autoraedae  N  F     1 1  F   [GTXDK]
> car;

The first, *autocinētum, -ī*, is from Greek αὐτοκίνητος, which I believe translates as *self-propelling*; the second, *autocinēticus, -a, -um* from αὐτοκινητικός, means *self-putting-in-motion*; the final, *autoraeda, -ae* is simply *self-cart*, as in self-acting or self-moving cart. *Auto-* is thus a useful prefix.

**Hence my suggestion for *motorcycle* in Latin: *autŏ*bĭ*rŏta, -ae*, in short *au*tŏ*rŏta, -ae*.**

Comment: According to Google, "motor" (mover) is Latin, and "cyclus" is Late Latin.  Thus, why wouldn't it be some derivative of motor+cyclus?

Comment: Certainly a valid question, @RonJohn. Were one to go for that solution, it would be more likely to be some derivative of motor + birota, as _cycle_ compares to _bicycle_ as _rota_ does to the already established _birota_. Now why not choose _motor_? Indeed why not? Cp. DE _auto_ with EN _car_ or _automobile_ to NO/DA/SV _bil_ and we can see how which new word for a new thing sticks, is quite unpredictable (_motorcycle_ is _motorsykkel_ in NO, despite automobile > bil). Will the new word be built off an existing one, or be a translation? Cp. EN _computer_ to NO _datamaskin_ (data machine).

Comment: I suggest you write up an answer with your suggestion.

Comment: The only Latin I know is the roots of English words,  (I had to verify that motorcycle didn't *only* have Greek origins before making the comment.)

Comment: Well, you already have the basics for you answer ready, so why not add it? You can tag one of us in a comment or in Conloqvivm, and we can have a quick look at it and see if there are any errors to correct. I feel it wrong to write up your suggestion as an answer and get the rumour points you would well deserve.

Answer (score 4):

Being in the territory of New Latin, any term can be of questionable authority. If an author doesn't like the terms used before and prefers a neologism instead, they can easily justify said neologism.

Some of the terms I'm suggesting are already mentioned in other answers. The commonness of any term could be on account of many different reasons, so keep them in mind.

[Adumbratio](https://neolatinlexicon.org/adumbratio-old/), a site full of New Latin and timeless Latin terms, gives *birota automata* and *birota automataria*, as well as *bicyclula motoria* and *autobirota*. These variations are due to variations in authors, though if you go to the website, it does cite the sources.

The Vatican's [Parvum Verborum Novatorum Lexicum](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/institutions_connected/latinitas/documents/rc_latinitas_20040601_lexicon_it.html) does not give a translation for motorcycle, but it does give a translation for *motoretta*— which means motor scooter in Italian—as *birotula automataria*, where *birotula* is a diminutive of *birota*.

I personally find *autobirota* to be my favorite, as it is a single word and makes sense. That being said, *birota automataria* seems to be holding its ground as a considerable option.